# Missing Permissions Error For Granting a Role

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm having an issue when trying to grant roles to server admins. For regular permissions it works fine, but if it's a server admin role, or some other role with permissions, even if I'm the owner, it gives the following error:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions
```

And the code I'm using is:

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages = True)
async def grant(ctx , user : discord.Member , role : discord.Role):
  await user.add_roles(role)
  await ctx.send(f"Our Comrade {user.name} has received the {role.name} role!")
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

`403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions` shows up not because *you* don't have permissions but rather because *the bot* doesn't have permissions. Try moving the bot's top role up the role hierarchy and give it all the required permissions. In this case, it needs to be above the admin role and have the `Manage Roles` permission.

Comment: I tried that but the same issue occurred. The bot has admin permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, and moving the bots role up the role hiearchy worked for me.