# disnake bot user.add_role results in 403 despite admin permissons

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

With my disnake bot I'm trying to add a role to a user. I am getting the following error:

```
File "/code/cogs/whitelist.py", line 298, in adduser
     await user.add_roles(role)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/disnake/member.py", line 997, in add_roles
     await req(guild_id, user_id, role.id, reason=reason)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/disnake/http.py", line 436, in request
     raise Forbidden(response, data)
disnake.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions
```

More info:

- the bot has admin permissions
- I'm using a slash command here. The bot has application command permissions.
- I'm trying to add a non-admin role
- I'm trying to add the role to a non-admin user

I'm adding the bot with the following permissions:

```
permissions=8&scope=bot%20applications.commands
```

Any idea why I'm getting permission denied?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Missing Permissions Error For Granting a Role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66947477/missing-permissions-error-for-granting-a-role)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is mostly due by the fact that **not only Discord roles can be administrators**, but they also have an order.

Your bot **can't assign roles higher than its highest one**, so probably that `role` is higher than the role that makes your bot administrator.

You just have to provide it an higher role, maybe the higher in the guild.

---

The order of the roles is given by the following menu.

[image]

In this case `ElFrost` is the highest role.

Comment: You are correct, that was the issue. Does that mean whenever you invite a bot to your server and you want it to be able to assign roles, you have to manually assign it a role at least as high as the highest role it should be able to assign to others? Or can the bot somehow ask for a role when it joins or assign itself a role?

Comment: When it joins you must take its role to the top. Anyway you can handle the 403 exception in case in a server your bot doesn't have that permission. Feel free to ask if you have more doubts, otherwise please accept my answer.

Comment: you have to move it's role to the top - meaning the server owner must do this manually, correct? So if I want someone to use my bot, I must tell them to do this e.g. by catching the 403 and responding to it

Comment: Exactly this. You got it. It's the only way of doing this for safety reasons. What's more you had the right idea: catching 403 and responding to the message should be OK

Comment: Happy to have helped! Please accept my answer to mark it as a working one ☑️